# Landscape Layout won't apply

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to use a different layout for landscape orientation. I followed the guide of school and because it didn't work a guide on the web.

What I have done:

- Add an extra directory for landscape
- Add the xml files (with the same name)
- I didn't add the config changes: orientation thing in my XML file

But as far as I find this is the only thing you need to do... Correct me if I am wrong.

If you need more information just let me know.

EDIT:

screenshot of files:

[image]

Screenshot of manifest:

[image]

Comment: How did you name the extra directory? Also what do you mean by "didn't add the config changes: orientation thing in my XML file"? Are you talking about `manifest.xml`?

Comment: what is the name of the extra directory you created?

Comment: layout-land is the name of the extra directory. @Umbo Yes that was the one. I saw it in some other posts that you can't do that but i didn't.

Comment: Can you post the relevant extract of the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one moment one of my changes was implemented but not all of them. So I did a clean of my build and ran it again and it worked. Probably the app had a sort of cashing.